# Bitrise: big increase in time spent on CocoaPods install step when upgrading to Xcode 12.3 stack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, bitrise

We're using Bitrise to build our Swift iOS app. Since upgrading the build stack from Xcode version 12.2 to 12.3 the `cocoapods-install` step suddenly started taking between 14-17 minutes instead of the usual 2-3 minutes. When downgrading back to Xcode 12.2 the pod install time goes back to around 2 minutes again.

When looking at the console output when the build is running it is clear that it's this command that is taking so long: `$ /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git -- cocoapods`. After inspecting the logs on our builds from before and after upgrading to Xcode 12.3 it looks like that command isn't even run on the `cocoapods-install` step on the Xcode 12.2 stack. Why does it have to be run on Xcode 12.3 and not 12.2? Any tips on how to decrease the time spent on this step?

Comment: Either cache your pods (bitrise has an option for this: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/caching/caching-cocoapods/), or include them in your git. Both are viable options with ups and downs, but it prevents you from running a `pod install` on your CI.

Why this takes so much longer on 12.3, no clue on that part sadly.

Comment: Recent CocoaPods versions should use a CDN instead of the github Specs repo. Sharing the Podfile might help additional diagnosis.